# How to set style according to the column name and cell value?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to highlight negative values with red color for some columns, and green color for another columns. (in column_colors dictionary)

How can i get the column name in `applymap` function?

```
return df.style.applymap(
    lambda val: column_colors[???]['negative_cell'] if val < 0 else column_colors[???]['positive_cell'],
    subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, column_colors_keys])
```

this is the dict:

```
  "column_colors": {
    "a": {
       "positive_cell": "color:red;",
       "negative_cell": "color:green;"
    },
    "b":{
       "positive_cell": "color:green;",
       "negative_cell": "color:red;"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`style.applymap` is applied element-wise so there is not an easy way to retrieve the "current" column name.

If you use `style.apply` (which is applied column-wise by default) it is trivial to get the "current" column name with the `.name` attribute:

```
column_colors = {
    "a": {
        "positive_cell": "color:red;",
        "negative_cell": "color:green;"
    },
    "b": {
        "positive_cell": "color:green;",
        "negative_cell": "color:red;"
    }
}

def apply_style(column):
    col_data = column_colors[column.name]
    return [col_data['positive_cell'] if val > 0 else col_data['negative_cell']
            for val in column]

df.style.apply(apply_style)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using a dataframe of the dictionaries to style with `np.where`

```
m = pd.DataFrame(column_colors) #creates a dataframe from column_colors dict
def myf(x):
    val = np.where(x>0 ,m.loc['positive_cell'], m.loc['negative_cell'])
    return pd.DataFrame(val,columns=x.columns,index=df.index)
df.style.apply(myf,axis=None,subset=[*column_colors.keys()])
```

---

[image]